# Fail on cf ic login. Auth error= InvalidToken

Tags: authentication, containers, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When running the command cf ic login i get the follow exception:

```
 $ cf ic login
 Deleting the old configuration file...
 Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
 INFO: 2016/08/02 11:17:44 Auth Error: {
     "code": "IC5097E",
     "description": "The bearer token is not valid: AUTH_WITH_NO_NAMESPACE. Log in to Cloud Foundry again to generate new token.",
     "incident_id": "1407-1470129461.247-5923962",
     "name": "InvalidToken",
     "rc": "401",
     "type": "Infrastructure"
 }
 FAILED
 A problem occurred with the login. Your session might have expired. Use "cf ic login" to log in again.
```

I've tried logout and login again but the same exception is thrown.

Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Have you logged in to Cloud Foundry/Bluemix before with "cf login"?

Comment: Yes, first i executed cf login (all ok), then I executed cf ic login. Only have this error on http://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net. On http://api.ng.bluemix.net i can login with cf ic login and no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cf ic namespace set <new_name>
```

Have you set the namespace for your organisation? If it's the first time you logged into your organisation. A namespace is a unique name to identify your private image repository on the Bluemix registry. When you create a container, you must specify an image's location by including the namespace with the image name.

Rules for the namespace:

- It can contain only lowercase letters, numbers, or underscores (_).
- It can be 4 - 30 characters. If you plan to manage containers from the command line, you might prefer to have a short namespace that can be typed quickly.
- It must be unique in the Bluemix registry.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cf ic init after you cf login ?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know this happens when you don't do a `cf login` before using `cf ic login`. Since you are able to do that in US South and the issue occurs only in UK region it could depend on the fact that you could need to initialize your container environment using `cf ic init`. I'd suggest you to take a look [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/252923/ibm-containers-error-the-bearer-token-is-not-valid.html) if the issue persists.

You could also try to use the new [*bx CLI*](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html) (command `bx ic`).